# Getting array out of bounds exception when updating a record

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, indexoutofboundsexception

I have created a simple address book program which allows the user to add and update a record. There is also a jtable on the address book which shows the user all the records in the address Book. I have recently added logic where the user updates an existing record and the table refreshes. But if I then click on the updated record or any record in the Jtable to display into the Jtext field I get a I get an Array Out of Bounds error.

Code for getting records from the Database

```
public void addTable() throws Exception {

    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    xtable = new JTable(tableModel);
    tableModel.addColumn("ID");
    tableModel.addColumn("First Name");
    tableModel.addColumn("Surname");
    tableModel.addColumn("Address Line 1");
    tableModel.addColumn("Address Line 2");
    tableModel.addColumn("Address Line 3");
    tableModel.addColumn("City");
    tableModel.addColumn("Post Code");
    tableModel.addColumn("Email Address");
    tableModel.addColumn("Phone Number");
    
    db.connectDb();
    String outQuery = "SELECT * FROM Contacts";
    db.myFs = db.st.executeQuery(outQuery);
    
    while (db.myFs.next()) {
        String id = db.myFs.getString("ContactID");
        String fName = db.myFs.getString("FirstName");
        String sName = db.myFs.getString("Surname");
        String adOne = db.myFs.getString("AddressLineOne");
        String adTwo = db.myFs.getString("AddressLineTwo");
        String adThree = db.myFs.getString("AddressLineThree");
        String cCity = db.myFs.getString("City");
        String pCode = db.myFs.getString("PostCode");
        String eAddress = db.myFs.getString("EmailAddress");
        String eName = db.myFs.getString("PhoneNumber");
        tableModel.insertRow(0, new Object[] { id, fName,sName, adOne, adTwo, adThree, cCity,
                pCode, eAddress, eName });
    }
    db.st.close();
    db.con.close();
    
    pane = new JScrollPane(xtable);
    pane.setBounds(700, 100, 400, 100);
    panel.add(pane);
    

}
```

Code to display record into JTextField

```
public void fetchRec() {
    xtable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            
        
            String col0 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),0);
            String col1 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),1);
            String col2 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),2);
            String col3 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),3);
            String col4 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),4);
            String col5 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),5);
            String col6 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),6);
            String col7 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),7);
            String col8 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),8);
            String col9 = (String) xtable.getValueAt(xtable.getSelectedRow(),9);
        
            idLabelField.setText(col0);
            firstNameLabelField.setText(col1);
            surNameLabelField.setText(col2);
            addressLineOneField.setText(col3);
            addressLineTwoField.setText(col4);
            addressLineThreeField.setText(col5);
            cityField.setText(col6);
            postCodeField.setText(col7);
            emailAddressField.setText(col8);
            phoneNumberField.setText(col9); 
            
            }
    });
}
```

Code to Update a record in the Db

```
    public void updateButton() {
    updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(idLabelField.getText());
        
            setID(number);
            setFirstName(firstNameLabelField.getText());
            setSurName(surNameLabelField.getText());
            setAddressLineOne(addressLineOneField.getText());
            setAddressLineTwo(addressLineTwoField.getText());
            setAddressLineThree(addressLineThreeField.getText());
            setCity(cityField.getText());
            setPostCode(postCode.getText());
            setEmailAddress(emailAddressField.getText());
            setPhoneNumber(phoneNumberField.getText());

            try {
                db.updateDB(getID(),getFirstName(), getSurName(), getAddressLineOne(), getAddressLineTwo(),
                        getAddressLineThree(), getCity(), getPostCode(), getEmailAddress(), getPhoneNumber());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                addTable();
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                
            
        }
    });
}
```

The error i am getting is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 8

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used for layout managers.

> I have recently added logic where the user updates an existing record and the table refreshes.

I would guess the problem is that you keep creating new components (ie. JTable and JScrollPane) and then add the components to the screen.

The problem is you never remove the previous components so you have multiple instances of each component being painted on the frame and your variables don't reference the visible components.

So the solution is create your `JTable` and `JScrollPane` and add the components to the frame when you first create the frame. Then, when you "referesh" the data you just create a new `DefaultTableModel` and use the `setModel(...)` method to update the table.

Or you can use `setRowCount(0)` of your current `DefaultTableModel` to remove all the current data and then use use the `addRow(...)` method to repopulate the model with the dat in the ResultSet.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.